# BitmapFactory FileNotFound and NullPointerException

Tags: android

```
E/BitmapFactory(31986): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
    /data/data/com.example.xyz/files/img/l/image_00tt.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
directory)
D/AndroidRuntime(31986): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(31986): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41849da0)
E/AndroidRuntime(31986): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(31986):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:704)
E/AndroidRuntime(31986):    at    com.example.xyz.Customlistadapter.getView(Customlistadapter.java:46)
```

Also this error is shown only once i.e when the data is getting loaded from the server first time. After that I never see this error.
The line that shows error is

```
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Image[position]), 32, 32, true);
```

Can anybody help me to catch both of those errors ie `FileNotFoundException` and `NullPointerException` for the bitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

I did the below to avoid the `NullPointerException`

```
if(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Image[position])!=null)
{
    Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Image[position]), 32, 32, true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
else
{
    Log.d("TAG", "unable to decode");
}
```